# php artisan command not working after changed evnvironment to local

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I enabled my local environment setting in `bootstrap/start.php`

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('homestead', 'localmachine'),

));
```

After that when I run any `php artisan`  command it's not giving any response. 
But if remove the `localmachine` everything become back to normal.

Laravel Framework version 4.2.11

Comment: Check `app/config/local` config files, probably these are missing some config info and artisan throws error.

Comment: recreated the local config and now it's working!!

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to regenerate the class maps of your package.
try

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

followed by

```
  composer update
```

hope that helps!